# Calling Azure Functions Runtime from Logic Apps

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-functions-runtime

I have on-premise azure functions create via the Azure Functions Runtime. How do I call these functions from a logic apps resource on the cloud. Based on what I have been reading I need to install the on-premise data gateway first. This will be the way logic apps will communicate to on-premise resources. However this communication seems to only be possible for local data sources sqlserver, biztalk server etc. How exactly do i angagne with my local functions. Is there a connector for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can expose your local machine using a tool such as:

- Ngrok
- Localtunnel
- Serveo
- Teleconsole
- Pagekite

and use the provided url as a proxy to call your local function. So your Logic App will call one of those services, which will route the request to your function.

Comment: Unfortunately company policy prohibits public exposure of local machines by any means.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your functions are HTTP triggered.

Calling on-prem HTTP resources directly from Logic Apps can be done, as you suggested, via the on-premises data gateway. You just need to create a [custom connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/custom-connectors/) for this.

There are tutorials under the official documentation, but as an external blog this one explains the required steps (for SOAP endpoint): https://www.codit.eu/blog/connecting-to-on-premise-http-endpoints-from-logic-app/

Comment: Unortunately it looks HTTP triggered functions are not available in Azure Functions Runtime (https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/11175). But thanks for the custom connector tip.

Comment: Sorry, I had forgotten that completely as I haven't got similar case myself in production. Thanks for the reminder! On-prem connections yes, but not functions.

Comment: Although, seems that with KEDA you can also publish HTTP triggers: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-kubernetes-keda#http-trigger-support